# nested Activity class and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nested, android-activity

I post here because I have a difficult question.

I have a class that extends TabNewsActivity of Activity

This class contains a nested class TabNewsActivity: DownloadData which extends to AsyncTask  >>

This class TabNewsActivity displays the recovered data from my web service, a spot DownloadData is asynchronous which allows me to retrieve the values ​​of my web service in a list.

To perform an update values ​​(in my application => refresh) I have to do this:

```
DownloadData (). Execute ();
```

But I can not do it out of my context TabNewsActivity: s

I would like a way to re execute this command, but in another tab for example.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest making your DownloadData subclass in a separate class file, not a nested class of TabNewsActivity.  You can pass it a Handler to act as a completion callback perhaps.  This way you can execute DownloadData from TabNewsActivity, and pass it a Handler to call in TabNewsActivity upon completion.  The same could hold true when calling it from another class.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask execute() method is static so you dont need an instance of anything to call it. You call it like this:

```
AsyncTask.execute();
```

That will run what you have in your doInBackground() method. As far as I know you should be able to call AsyncTask.execute() anywhere in your app as long as you import AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask inside of a Service.